# QTranslator doesn't work

Tags: qt

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QTranslator>
#include<QObject>
#include<QTextCodec>
#include<QWidget>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load("app_zh_CN.qm");
    app.installTranslator(&translator);

    QWidget widget;
    widget.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Hello World!"));
    widget.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

> 

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

TRANSLATIONS += app_zh_CN.ts
```

The Gui interface is "Hello World!" also.. But in my file.qm is be translate to "你好!"(chinese)...
where is the preblem ? who can help me..

Comment: `translator.load()` returns a bool. Is it returning true or false for you?

Comment: @Arnold Spence: Thank you .. the value returned is false... What is wrong ?

Comment: Try following the instructions provided by @Dave Mateer in his answer :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your example works for me if I put the .qm file in the "correct" spot. (See below.) Make sure you are doing all the steps:

1. Run `lupdate` to create the .ts file.
2. Do your translation in Linguist and save the .ts file.
3. Run `lrelease` to compile the .ts file to a .qm file.
4. Copy the .qm file to the correct location.

My guess is that #4 is going bad. The documentation for `QTranslator::load` states:

> If *directory* is not specified, the directory of the application's
>   executable is used (i.e., as applicationDirPath()).

However, I had to put the .qm file in the folder **above** the executable to get it to work as is. Unless I'm misunderstanding the docs, this is a Qt bug, but one that is simple to workaround. If I explicitly gave the directory as `app.applicationDirPath`, it worked in the executable folder. You could also specify a separate directory. For example:

`translator.load("app_zh_CN.qm");` works with:

```
[MyApp]
  app_zh_CN.qm
  [debug]
    MyApp.exe
```

`translator.load("app_zh_CN.qm", app.applicationDirPath());` works with:

```
[MyApp]
  [debug]
    app_zh_CN.qm
    MyApp.exe
```