# Qt tr() not working if i am using in static member

Tags: c++, qt, localization, internationalization, translation

Please let me know why it is not working i am new in Qt. here is the code

```
class Transl
{
   public:
   static const QString str;
};
const QString Transl::str = QObject::tr("Hello world");

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load("trans_la");
    app.installTranslator(&translator);

    QPushButton hello(Transl::str);
    hello.resize(100, 30);
    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

My trans_la.ts file contains this which i generate by lupdate.

```
<TS version="2.0">
<context>
    <name>QObject</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.cpp" line="10"/>
        <source>Hello world</source>
        <translation>Orbis, te saluto!</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Then I do lrelease which generate trans_la.qm. But when i run my executable instead of showing the translated string it shows "Hello world". Please suggest me why it is not working.

Comment: Maybe it's just because your compiler initializes Transl::str before executing main()?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Qt Linguist manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtlinguist/linguist-programmers.html) and search for the section marked `Using QT_TR_NOOP() and QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP()` about two-thirds of the way down the page.

### Plus

It's a good idea to check the returned boolean from translator.load(). I couldn't get this to work and noticed the file wasn't loading correctly. Then I discovered [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228859/633267), and manually moved my `trans_fr.qm` file to the directory above the .exe.  I assume this is a bug since the [hello translation walkthrough](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtlinguist/hellotr.html) never mentions that this is necessary.