# How to use translation in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use **Qt**'s `tr()` function for translation.

In `.pro` file I have:

```
TRANSLATIONS += languages/myapp_en.ts \
                languages/myapp_es.ts
```

and in `main.cpp`:

```
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("myapp_es"); //espanol
app.installTranslator(&translator);
```

I run `lupdate` and the files `myapp_en.ts`, `myapp_es.ts` are generated.

I edit the file `myapp_es.ts`, for example:

```
<context>
    <name>Example</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../example.cpp" line="24"/>
        <source>Good night</source>
        <translation>Buenas noches</translation> <!-- THIS IS MY EDIT -->
    </message>
</context>
```

Then I run `lrelease` so the files `myapp_en.qm`, `myapp_es.qm` are generated.

Then I use `tr()` in code like this:

```
button->setText(tr("Good night"));
```

inside the constructor of a `Q_OBJECT` class.

But the text is still showing in English ("Good night"), and not in Spanish.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

[Putting the `*.qm` files in the correct directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228859/900394) solved the problem. Just had to make sure it's in the Release directory and not the Debug.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of translator.load?

Comment: OK checked it just now. It's `false`

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the extension `.qm` and correct path when calling `translator.load`:

```
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("languages/myapp_es.qm"); //espanol
app.installTranslator(&translator);
```

Comment: Didn't work. `translator.load()` is still returning false, and the words aren't translated.

Comment: I think you also need to add `languages/` in your case, updated my answer

Comment: Still not working after adding `languages/`. The files exist like the following: `workspace > *.cpp , *.h > languages > *.ts , *.qm`. I can't figure where the executable resides though

Comment: check `QDir::currentPath()`

Comment: OK this helped me find the executable. I moved the `*.qm`'s there and now it's returning `true` (had to **not add** "languages" though). No translation though. The English text still appears

Comment: Please remove `<location filename="../example.cpp" line="24"/>` from the .ts file and copy the .qm file again after building

Comment: Same result... Also tried to download **Qt**'s `linguist` software and use it to edit the `.ts` file instead of editing it manually. Same result...

Comment: I'm running out of ideas... Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: it was always working fine for me without ".qm". You can specify directory where translation files are located as second argument to `translator.load()`, otherwise it is current directory [doc link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load). Are you sure that translation is loaded before application's widget ?

Comment: OK it's funny. After putting `*.qm` in the right directory, I debugged to see that `translator.load()` returns `true`. And it did. And when I ran the program I saw no translation. Duh... `.qm` was in the Debug directory. So yeah putting it in the Release directory works

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

after installing translator you have to call retranslate of ui generated class if applied or call tr again

Answer (score 0):

From the other answers I can see that you're now getting `true` for load, so it's finding the translation file. What it could then be is that you're installing the translation after the system has already initialised the UI, so you can do one of two things:

1. Install the translator before you create your UI, for me it would go:

   ```
    translator.load(someTranslation)
    a.installTranslator(&translator)
    MainWindow w;
   ```
2. Install the translator after you create the UI, which if you're providing multiple language support is most likely where you'll want it. Qt provides a `retranslateUi()` function, which when called will update the user interface. There's a question here which shows this in more depth: [How to translate language in Qt on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224101/how-to-translate-language-in-qt-on-the-fly). There's a bit more code required for handling the language change event, but it does allow for dynamic language updates.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing (1). I'll try '2', thanks